# Noto Emoji Monochrome Font (Google): Extract emojis as individual .svg files?

Tags: svg, ttf, emoji

I need to access a few emojis as SVG from the Noto Emoji Monochrome font. It's trivial to do so for the colored version at: https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/svg . But no such place exists for the monochrome version.

How do I access individual emojis as SVG from the monochrome version? Do I need to convert the .ttf file? Or extract them somehow?

Specifically I need:

### Font Sources

- https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji
- https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji

### EDIT

https://github.com/adobe-fonts/noto-emoji-svg exists with monochrome, but the emojis are outdated.

Comment: Just an idea: Set the font in a vector application, create outlines, save as SVG.

Answer (score 1):

There are some online extractors
(like https://iconly.io/tools/font-to-icons-converter ie.)

Or if you have Illustrator, or another Vector software, you can type your font, vectorise it, and then save it as SVG, letter by letter.